# Cannot access a disposed object with MemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting this message:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A
>   common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
>   from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
>   context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
>   are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
>   using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
>   the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
>   instances.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAllTags()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(GetAll());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ControllerHelper.LogAndReturnBadRequest(_logger, ex);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<TagDto> GetAll()
    {
            IEnumerable<TagDto> tags;
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.States, out tags))
            {
                tags = _service.GetAll()?.Select(t => _mapper.Map<TagDto>(t));

                if(tags != null)
                    _cache.Set(CacheKeys.States, tags);
            }

            return tags;
    }
```

Startup.cs

`services.AddMemoryCache();`

I was debugging the code line by line, but even after the last line of my code, there is no error at all.

The error I saw was in Kestrel console. **Worth to notice, the error only happen when fetching tags from the _cache, not happen on the first time when tags fetched directly from database.**

[image]

Here is what I got from Postman request:

[image]

Many similar questions referring to dispose objects, but here you can see that I do not have dispose(), or using() in my code.

Comment: What line are you getting this error on?

Comment: @RonBeyer I was debugging it line by line, but even after return Ok(GetAll()); there is no exception happen. I will update my post to include the response in Postman and error in Kestrel console.

Comment: @RonBeyer I updated the error from Kestrel console and attached the postman response

Comment: Seems like your DbContext is disposed.

Comment: hi @KirillPolishchuk but I stored the tags in my cache already, so even DbContext is disposed, it shouldn't affect my cache, isn't it?

Comment: @Franva - were you able to solve this issue? I am getting hit with the exact same problem. I tried the ToList() and still no luck. My Db context dependency is transient and is injected in service layer as scoped. I noticed that shifting to a singleton instance removes this error; but that is not what I want

Comment: Works - My resultset from database had multiple 'IEnumerable' properties - I had to invoke ToList on each for explicit evaluation.

Comment: Just FYI, closely related link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047209/why-is-dbcontext-is-disposed-after-putting-it-in-imemorycache-net-core-ef-co

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you need to hydrate the results of your query before storing in in the cache. Linq uses *deferred execution*, which means that the underlying source won't actually be queried until you try to enumerate the results. So you are just storing a *query* in the cache, and by the time you try to retrieve the actual data, the underlying context is disposed.

Add a `ToList` to your query and store the list in the cache:

```
tags = _service.GetAll()?.Select(t => _mapper.Map<TagDto>(t)).ToList();
```

I would also note that the result of a linq query that returns a sequence will *never* be null. It might be *empty*, so if you don't want to cache an empty result you could change your null check to `if (tags.Any())`.

Comment: Just FYI, closely related link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047209/why-is-dbcontext-is-disposed-after-putting-it-in-imemorycache-net-core-ef-co