# Simple C# Noop Statement

Tags: c#, no-op

What is a simple Noop statement in C#, that doesn't require implementing a method?
(Inline/Lambda methods are OK, though.)

My current use case: I want to occupy the catch-block of a try-catch, so I can step into it while debugging and inspect the exception.
I'm aware I should probably be handling/logging the exception anyway, but that's not the point of this exercise.

Comment: Can't you just put the breakpoint on the closing `}` of the catch block?

Comment: You can also break on the `catch (...)` and step once if you want to look at the exception.

Comment: @Porges I thought the same thing, but I'm finding that the exception variable isn't bound when doing this.

Comment: return isn't really a noop, it does something (returns), and you can't break on an empty statement - which is a shame. It would have been ideal for this purpose.

Comment: In addition to @George, you don't need anything. Just put a breakpoint on the _opening_ brace.

Comment: I'm impressed something so simple can generate so many different answers.

Comment: A breakpoint on the opening brace has bound the `e`(`x`) variable, and will only break on that exception.

Comment: This just smells of something bad to me. Almost all suggestions cause cryptic constructions or exception-hiding code. The question that comes to my mind is: "Why only interested in the exception at debug time?"

Comment: @Protector: Perhaps execution is slipping past the thin edges of the `}`. You could try creating a stiffer hold using `catch (Exception e) {{{{{{{{{{ }}}}}}}}}}`.

Comment: @Protector: are we talking `catch(Exception e) {}` or about `catch { }` ?

Comment: @Protector one are you using release or debug builds? The `catch (Exception e) {}` will get collapsed to `catch {}` in a release build.

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson: Holy crap, having the project set to Release was indeed causing a problem here! I always assumed that when debugging a project, Visual Studio automatically uses Debug!

Comment: A noop is, more technically, a single CPU instruction that does nothing so that the CPU will pause for just 1 hertz.  I was wondering today if C# (or at least MSIL) had a legit NOOP statement.  In this day and age, NOOPs may seem unnecessary and, honestly, I can't think of many good case where you should use C# at such a low-level.  However, when you have very tight hardware constraints for certain types of projects, a NOOP or two may be necessary to get a well timed, synchronization process to work properly.  Does anyone know if a true, single-cycle CPU pause exists for .Net?

Comment: @RLH you should not be using NO-OPs for timing in modern apps.  Such patterns do not play well with Multi-Tasking or Mobile Hardware (they eat up CPU time that other apps can't use, and cause a higher cpu utilization which wastes battery power).

Comment: if I need something to break on, I always add:
int breakpoint = 0; This has the side benefit of creating a warning (unused local variable) so I remember to remove it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you really want noop, then this defines a nameless action that doesn't do anything, and then invokes it, causing nothing to happen:

```
((Action)(() => { }))();
```

Comment: You like this one, but you don't like the Noop method? Why?

Comment: @David Heffernan, because now there is only one line to remove when I decide to discard it. Lazy? Perhaps.

Comment: @Protector one Why would you ever need to remove the Noop method? I'd have thought laze (an admirable trait in many ways) would have you preferring to write `Noop();` than `((Action)(() => { }))();` which seems a little bracket heavy for my liking.

Comment: It's also still a method call.

Comment: @David Heffernan: If you only ever work on one project, writing Noop/0 once is preferable, sure. If you're working on multiple code bases, I'd prefer just memorizing a (relatively) simple statement.

Comment: The answer sounds like it was written by Douglas Adams.

Comment: I think @AnthonyVO's solution is, by far, the cleanest solution. A simple `{/* Noop */}` statement is a single line that executes nothing, is self documenting, and does not leave one wondering if some code has been accidentally deleted (as a lone semicolon will do).

Answer (score 83):

The standard empty statement/noop operation in c# is

```
;
```

as in:

```
if (true)
    ;
```

([relevant documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

this specifically addresses your use case (just place a break-point on the ; line, or otherwise step to it), is minimal, and is directly supported by the environment just for this purpose (so you even if you're doing complex things, like looking at the compiled source, you won't have any additional noise/etc.. to worry about from the compiler/optimizer/etc...) - and has the additional benefit of putting up a warning, as a reminder to clean it out of your code when you're done debugging/push to production

Comment: IMO the right answer too. I would add a comment like `// NOOP` to let know that was on purpose.

Comment: A single `;` will just be compiled away, so from a behavioral standpoint it's not a noop. (It should _do_ nothing, not _be_ nothing.)

Comment: @Protectorone, but you can put breakpoint on it

Comment: @Protectorone So with an `if (i > 1) ;` , will the entire if be compiled away as well?

Comment: @nl-x I expect it will!

Comment: @nl-x Not if ’i’ is just a simple variable… Given that it's lowercase, let's assume it is. I would be really surprised if the current C# compiler in .NET Core doesn't compile it away.

Comment: @Protectorone Try it: `for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) ;` ... You'll see that will execute for a couple of seconds. So it's not compiled away.

Comment: @nl-x an infinite loop remains an infinite loop, even if it contains a noop. Your code provides a very useful estimate of loop overhead cost (in time / space)

Answer (score 17):

If you want to break into the method you could hardcode a breakpoint:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Alternatively if you don't compile in release mode, the following line will emit IL which you can break on:

```
var a = 1;
```

You could also write a Debug.Break() that is specific to your machine:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[Obsolete("Please remove me before checkin.")]
public static void Break()
{
    #IF DEBUG
    if (Dns.GetHostName() == "PROTECTORONE")
        Debugger.Break();
    #ENDIF
}
```

Note that because of `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` that method will not get called in call sites during a RELEASE build.

Comment: `Debugger.Break` is fine for my use case, but I'd rather have something that wouldn't be annoying if it accidentally gets committed.

Comment: @Protector one give that Break() a go, it is borderline hack.

Comment: @Protector one - now it will even warn you that is being used during a build; and it won't go into RELEASE builds (the C# compiler won't call the method).

Answer (score 12):

> The standard empty statement/noop operation in C# is `;` as in `if (true) ;`.
> - blueberryfields

**But** using that standard `;` as a branch of an `if` statement makes MS Visual Studio 2010 show a Warning: "Possible mistaken empty statement". (Warning CS0642, though VS2010 doesn't tell me that or link to actual help for the warning.)

**Worse,** the MSDN C# Language Specification does not mention that *actually coding* that empty statement as a branch of an `if` statement provokes Warning CS0642 "Possible mistaken empty statement". (Warning because it is "bad form", potentially ambiguous.)

**Worse yet,** it looks like VS2010 provides no way to NEATLY suppress an individual warning. I would have to insert `#pragma warning disable CS0642` before the line(s) and [optionally] `#pragma warning disable CS0642` after. To me, this is uglier than the warning. I'd be better off using `{ }` in place of `;`. (I might use an override that is a little less ugly.)

I looked here for a "C# no-op" because I wanted an alternative to the "empty statement", to get rid of that warning. I don't need a checkpoint. I just want a do-[absolutely]-nothing that is not ambiguous like "the empty statement".

The alternative must not provoke SOME OTHER warning. `int u;` is no good because it provokes Warning "The variable 'u' is declared but never used". `int u = 0;` is no good because it provokes Warning "The variable 'u' is assigned but its value is never used".

If `noop;` (or similar) were added as an unambiguous empty statement (NOT a macro definition), that would be great.

If `noop();` (or similar) were a function with an empty body (which can disappear completely when the compiler inlines it), that would almost be great.

When the branch is only one statement, I often omit the surrounding `{` and `}` LINES because they are not needed and they stretch the code vertically, making it harder to read. The inconsistency in the language is that I can't omit the the surrounding `{` and `}` LINES when they surround ZERO statements. I can compact the two lines to `{ }` on the same line, but that is inconsistent. I think `;` on a line is the neatest solution, and it should NOT cause a warning on the [unstated] grounds of "bad form". I think warning CS0642 should have defaulted to OFF. I think the following code should be acceptable as-is:

```
if (condition1)
  action1;
else if (condition2)
  ;  // (do nothing)
else if (condition3)
  action3;
else if (condition4)
  ;  // (do nothing)
else if (condition5)
  action5;
else
  action99;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can write a function that does nothing.

```
public static void Noop()
{
}
```

Comment: This is violating the "no method"-rule.

Comment: @Protector The "no method" rule is arbitrary and I for one would simply ignore it

Comment: @David: It's not arbitrary given that it's one of pre-requisites of the question. One can call into question whether it's a *sensible* pre-requisite, but without that pre-requisite I assume the question wouldn't even exist. So the answer ought to *either* argue against the pre-requisite *or* given an answer which matches it - rather than just violating the pre-requisite as if it hadn't been stated.

Comment: @Jon Agreed that arguing against would improve this answer

Comment: If you were debugging a release build then this would get optimized away.

Comment: I prefer this. forget the Question's rule. This would be more readable hence cleaner and more manageable

Comment: This is the best option for my purposes because you can't set a breakpoint on just a semi-colon. Although I would prepend the function with [Conditional("DEBUG")] .

Answer (score 8):

You can just write:

```
catch {
    ;
}
```

The empty statement with a single semicolon is the C# NOOP.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question and, technically, this answer doesn't relate to the asker's use case.  However, there is a NOOP instruction in CIL, which is `nop`.  As an experiment, take the following CIL application.

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}

.assembly Test
{
    .ver 1:0:1:0
}
.module test.exe

.method static void main() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint

    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop

    ret
}
```

If you compile the application, and decompile it with a tool like ILSpy, to C#, this is the contents of the main() method:

```
static void main()
{
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing there.  However, if we want to verify that the CIL compiler didn't optimize out these `nop` statements, we can view our application in decompiled IL code in ILSpy, and this is what we see for the main method:

```
.method static privatescope 
    void main$PST06000001 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 5 (0x5)
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: nop
    IL_0002: nop
    IL_0003: nop
    IL_0004: ret
} // end of method '<Module>'::main
```

CIL is certainly compiling the `nop` instructions into the assembly.  Since C# has no implementation of this instruction, these `nop` commands are not shown within the disassembled C# code.

I don't have a license for Reflector but I imagine if you decompile these binaries with Reflector you would get similar output for C#.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
GC.KeepAlive(e);
```

where `e` is the exception variable?

(I haven't tried putting a break point on the catch declaration itself. It feels like you *ought* to be able to do that, precisely for this reason. But whether it works or not is a different matter.)

Or somewhat more cryptically, assuming you've already got a using directive for `System.LINQ`:

```
"".AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: But, "that will box any value type values", according to a comment by a very intelligent man here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611844/simplest-c-code-to-poll-a-property

Comment: Ah yes, quite embarrassing… But it would be nice if I could use this noop in more general situations as well.

Comment: @Jon Skeet in debug, the lifetime of e is extended to the end of the method, so why KeepAlive ?

Comment: @Felice: Precisely because it'll have no effect. The question is *asking* for a simple way of doing nothing. I reckon `GC.KeepAlive` fits that bill nicely.

Comment: @Protector one: If you want a more general no-op, it's probably worth writing a separate method for it.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answers that directly answer the question.

---

If you just want to break, then you could always put the breakpoint on the opening `{` or closing `}` of the `catch` block.

Comment: This isn't working for me… Visual Studio never initializes the Exception variable when I do this.

Comment: Try the opening `{` brace. I can see the exception in an empty catch block. You do need to write `catch(Exception e)` of course, and live with the unused warning.

Comment: Ok, so this _is_ working when you have the build configuration set to Debug. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

After considering various options I decided that a pair of empty brackets and a terse comment were cleanest.  No extra code, self-documenting, and far more obvious than a single semicolon.

```
{/* Noop */}
```

e.g.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {/* Noop */}
else if (Data.ContainsKey(key))
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Any dev coming to this line will immediately know what the intention was and that it wasn't a mistake. The solution in the accepted answer is way too messy and the generally accepted noop, a lone semicolon, isn't obvious that it was intentional. This should be the standard noop we all use.

Answer (score 6):

Lots of great solutions! My go to is:

```
_ = "";
```

_ is used when you want to acknowledge there is a return value, but you don't want or need it. It can quiet the compiler from telling you aren't getting the return value.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for no-op setter:  set => _ = value;

Answer (score 4):

Well the NOP in C# exists, as in C and is `';'` and its correct definition is "*the empty statement*", but for the usage you intend, is enought to put the breakpoint in the closing catch bracket...
There is no needing to Keep Alive anithing, since Tthe lifetime of an object reference in a method is extended to the end of the method when the debugger is attached. So you simply need to write

```
catch(Exception exception)
{
}
```

and put the breakpoint on the closing bracket and see the exception content.

Comment: Actually, neither solutions appear to be working for me! If I use `;`, Visual Studio automatically skips it.

Comment: @Protrector one, it should jump the brakpoint on the '}' that will works for your needing.

Comment: I wouldn't really call `;` a nop. A nop is something that does nothing, but a lone `;` is nothing at all :)

Comment: @Porges You are right, it is well defined as "The Empty Statement"

Comment: Works for my, breakpoint goes to the end of the block and debugger stops there.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to debug a release (optimised) build? It is normally the optimiser that removes unreferenced variables and empty blocks.

Two solutions:

- Debug in a debug build.
- Put a break point on the `catch` itself and use `$exception` – created by the debugger to reference the exception in flight – in the Locals tool window.

Comment: Ah, the Locals-window trick is nice! Solves my current problem, at least.

Comment: At first I didn't understand your "Debug in a debug build" remark, but this was indeed something I should have been doing.

Answer (score 3):

Why over-engineer this?

```
var x = 0;
```

works just fine :)

Comment: This was my instinct as well but Visual Studio throws a warning on this method since the variable is unused. I ended up using @blueberryfields trick with the semicolon =>  ; //noop

Comment: Any time i've done this i've always add `x++;` after it. I want to make sure the compiler doesn't wash it away.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to @AHM 's answer since I wanted an easy way to do NOOP for debugging purposes (communicating with AB PLC CompactLogix and ran into errors only really visible in Disassembly because of C++ library DLL import in C#).

I took the one-liner

```
((Action)(() => { }))();
```

and put it into a snippet named ***noop.snippet*** then placed it in the folder named My Code Snippets.
(*Tools -> Code Snippets Manager -> Location*) OR Chord (*Ctrl+K,Ctrl+B*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>noop</Title>
            <Shortcut>noop</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet to inject an assembly (x86) equivalent of the NOOP command into the code's disassembly.</Description>
            <Author>Jay Whaley</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp">
            <![CDATA[// Forces a psuedo NOOP in disassembly
                ((Action)(() => { }))();
            $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

This helps to make it a quick use shortcut in case low level communication becomes muddled and requires this to be a common debugging tactic. The actual assembly generated is as follows, but there're [some posts about how to use *actual assembly* inline in C#.](https://esozbek.me/inline-assembly-in-csharp-and-dotnet/)

[image: Disassembly generated from invoking a nameless action]

Answer (score 0):

Reliable solution

```
try
{
   blablablablaStatemnt();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    #IF DEBUG
       Debugger.Break();
    #END IF
}
```

As simple as this!

Otherwise

## breakpoints

can be very usefull;

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did when I was writing some "Fakes" for unit tests and some of the methods were to be left blank.

```cs
public void SetToken(string token)
{
    // Method intentionally left empty
}
```

I followed the intellisense cues and got the above.  My environment is Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score -4):

I quite like this, just because it will confuse whoever comes across it:

```
catch (SomeException e)
{
    lock(e);
}
```

Comment: And whoever comes along to maintain will just marvel at your creativity and ingenuity - seriously, confusing people with code is not the way to go at all. That's one of the very things we're trying to get away from with human readable coding these days...

Comment: @GrantThomas Pretty sure he's being humorous.